# Assign Div data attribute as Data Source to JQuery AutoComplete

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using a **JS** method to assign the names of computer languages to data attribute of `div`
e.g

```
<div id="Languages" data-Languages=''></div>
```

and `js` code

```
var langs='["Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "C#"]';
$('#Languages').data('Languages', langs);
```

but when i type text in the textbox it gives me an error
Object Expected
i am using this line for autocomplete

```
$(function () { 
    $("#tags").autocomplete({ source: $('#Languages').data('Languages') }); 
});
```

it works totally fine when i make another variable and pass it as a source as implemented in jquery [website](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

i want to handle it with div's data attribute because in future i want to use `JSON` that fetches autocomplete data on page load and assign it to div data attribute.

sorry if that question sounds stupid, its my 2nd day with `jquery` and all that stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is you are assigning data to div outside page ready function, when div is not actually been loaded on page. try below mentions code, it works fine for me.

```
$(function () { 
    var langs = ["Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "C#"];
    $('#locations').data('languages', langs);
    $("#tags").autocomplete({ 
       source: $('#locations').data('languages') }); 
});
```

Comment: btw why are you puting your array in data when you can use it directly. like $("#tags").autocomplete({ source: langs });

Comment: man basically there is a thing i want to clear, that i am using a javascript funtion that calls on "body onload" event, and then that method is assigning the data source to the div, your code is fine and works for me but please make me clear that where should i bind the data source to the div? on load or somewhere else?

Comment: in future i will make my code work with json and retrieve all those tags from server side

Comment: well when you write code under $(function(){}); it makes sure your DOM has been loaded and can be used but when you use your DOM outside this function, that means its not been loaded hence assigning data to it won't work. you should always bind data source to div or any other operation with div in onload function only.

Comment: very nice explanation, i thank you for your time and consideration

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is your problem exactly but you have single quotes around your array, making it a string.

it should be:

```
var langs = ["Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "C#"];
```

Comment: definitely the problem, data needs to be an array

Comment: i've made the change now. but still the same error "Object Expected" :|

Answer (score 4):

your langs is like '' which makes it a string. you need an array which behaves like a source for autocomplete. Also there is a mismatch in id and key of data you are trying. try this

```
var langs = ["Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "C#"];
$('#locations').data('languages', langs);
$(function () { $("#tags").autocomplete({ 
  source: $('#locations').data('languages') }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not much different from @Rahul solution.

but maybe you want to read directly from the data attribute:

```
var langs = ["Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "C#"];

$('#locations').attr('data-Languages', langs);

$(function () { $("#tags").autocomplete({ 
    source: $('#locations').data('languages').split(',')}); 
});
```

working example: http://jsbin.com/oyusub/4/